# Jmeter Apache Dashboard report is blank

Tags: graph, jmeter, report

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDg9D.png)    JMeter log file:

```
2017-05-16 10:36:13,363 INFO o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: Setting Locale to en_US
2017-05-16 10:36:13,382 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Loading user properties from: user.properties
2017-05-16 10:36:13,384 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Loading system properties from: system.properties
2017-05-16 10:36:13,392 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Copyright (c) 1998-2017 The Apache Software Foundation
2017-05-16 10:36:13,392 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Version 3.2 r1790748
2017-05-16 10:36:13,392 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: java.version=1.8.0_121
2017-05-16 10:36:13,392 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
2017-05-16 10:36:13,393 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.name=Windows 7
2017-05-16 10:36:13,393 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.arch=amd64
2017-05-16 10:36:13,393 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.version=6.1
2017-05-16 10:36:13,393 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: file.encoding=Cp1252
2017-05-16 10:36:13,393 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Max memory     =536870912
2017-05-16 10:36:13,393 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Available Processors =2
2017-05-16 10:36:13,400 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Default Locale=English (United States)
2017-05-16 10:36:13,400 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: JMeter  Locale=English (United States)
2017-05-16 10:36:13,400 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: JMeterHome=D:\ApacheJMeter_3.2_Win_O\apache-jmeter-3.2\apache-jmeter-3.2
2017-05-16 10:36:13,401 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: user.dir  =D:\ApacheJMeter_3.2_Win_O\apache-jmeter-3.2\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin
2017-05-16 10:36:13,401 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: PWD       =D:\ApacheJMeter_3.2_Win_O\apache-jmeter-3.2\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin
2017-05-16 10:36:13,403 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: IP: 172.25.127.51 Name: HYDHTC397604D FullName: HYDHTC397604D.ad.infosys.com
2017-05-16 10:36:13,406 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Setting property 'jmeter.reportgenerator.outputdir' to:'D:\ApacheJMeter_3.2_Win_O\apache-jmeter-3.2\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin\Output'
2017-05-16 10:36:13,414 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Default base='D:\ApacheJMeter_3.2_Win_O\apache-jmeter-3.2\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin'
2017-05-16 10:36:13,414 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Set new base='D:\ApacheJMeter_3.2_Win_O\apache-jmeter-3.2\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin'
2017-05-16 10:36:13,602 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Testplan (JMX) version: 2.2. Testlog (JTL) version: 2.2
2017-05-16 10:36:13,630 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file encoding UTF-8
2017-05-16 10:36:13,638 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Using SaveService properties version 3.2
2017-05-16 10:36:13,650 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Loading file: TC_CreateItem.jmx
2017-05-16 10:36:13,719 INFO o.a.j.p.h.c.CookieManager: Settings: Delete null: true Check: true Allow variable: true Save: false Prefix: COOKIE_
2017-05-16 10:36:13,746 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2017-05-16 10:36:13,746 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xhtml+xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2017-05-16 10:36:13,747 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2017-05-16 10:36:13,747 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2017-05-16 10:36:13,747 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/vnd.wap.wml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser
2017-05-16 10:36:13,747 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/css is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.CssParser
2017-05-16 10:36:14,362 INFO o.a.j.e.KeyToolUtils: keytool found at 'keytool'
2017-05-16 10:36:14,364 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder SSL Proxy will use keys that support embedded 3rd party resources in file D:\ApacheJMeter_3.2_Win_O\apache-jmeter-3.2\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin\proxyserver.jks
2017-05-16 10:36:14,403 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Creating summariser <summary>
2017-05-16 10:36:14,412 INFO o.a.j.r.d.ReportGenerator: ReportGenerator will use for Parsing the separator: ','
2017-05-16 10:36:14,412 INFO o.a.j.r.d.ReportGenerator: Will generate report at end of test from  results file: testresults.csv
2017-05-16 10:36:14,413 INFO o.a.j.r.d.ReportGenerator: Reading report generator properties from: D:\ApacheJMeter_3.2_Win_O\apache-jmeter-3.2\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin\reportgenerator.properties
2017-05-16 10:36:14,420 INFO o.a.j.r.d.ReportGenerator: Merging with JMeter properties
2017-05-16 10:36:14,430 INFO o.a.j.r.c.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: Property 'jmeter.reportgenerator.temp_dir' not found, using default value 'temp' instead.
2017-05-16 10:36:14,435 INFO o.a.j.r.c.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: Property 'jmeter.reportgenerator.apdex_per_transaction' not found, using default value 'null' instead.
2017-05-16 10:36:14,435 INFO o.a.j.r.c.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: apdex_per_transaction : {} is empty, not APDEX per transaction customization
2017-05-16 10:36:14,435 INFO o.a.j.r.c.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: Property 'jmeter.reportgenerator.start_date' not found, using default value 'null' instead.
2017-05-16 10:36:14,435 INFO o.a.j.r.c.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: Property 'jmeter.reportgenerator.end_date' not found, using default value 'null' instead.
2017-05-16 10:36:14,435 INFO o.a.j.r.c.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: Property 'jmeter.reportgenerator.date_format' not found, using default value 'null' instead.
2017-05-16 10:36:14,436 INFO o.a.j.r.c.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: Will use date range start date: null, end date: null
2017-05-16 10:36:14,444 INFO o.a.j.r.c.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: Property 'jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.activeThreadsOverTime.exclude_controllers' not found, using default value 'false' instead.
2017-05-16 10:36:14,444 INFO o.a.j.r.c.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: Property 'jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.timeVsThreads.exclude_controllers' not found, using default value 'false' instead.
2017-05-16 10:36:14,444 INFO o.a.j.r.c.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: Property 'jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.responseTimeDistribution.exclude_controllers' not found, using default value 'false' instead.
2017-05-16 10:36:14,444 INFO o.a.j.r.c.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: Property 'jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.transactionsPerSecond.exclude_controllers' not found, using default value 'false' instead.
2017-05-16 10:36:14,445 INFO o.a.j.r.c.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: Property 'jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.responseTimePercentiles.exclude_controllers' not found, using default value 'false' instead.
2017-05-16 10:36:14,446 INFO o.a.j.r.c.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: Property 'jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.responseTimePercentilesOverTime.exclude_controllers' not found, using default value 'false' instead.
2017-05-16 10:36:14,446 INFO o.a.j.r.c.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: Property 'jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.responseTimesOverTime.exclude_controllers' not found, using default value 'false' instead.
2017-05-16 10:36:14,447 INFO o.a.j.r.c.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: Property 'jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.connectTimeOverTime.exclude_controllers' not found, using default value 'false' instead.
2017-05-16 10:36:14,447 INFO o.a.j.r.c.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: Property 'jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.latenciesOverTime.exclude_controllers' not found, using default value 'false' instead.
2017-05-16 10:36:14,449 INFO o.a.j.r.c.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: Property 'jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.filters_only_sample_series' not found, using default value 'true' instead.
2017-05-16 10:36:14,449 INFO o.a.j.r.c.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: Property 'jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.show_controllers_only' not found, using default value 'false' instead.
2017-05-16 10:36:14,458 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2017-05-16 10:36:14,462 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2017-05-16 10:36:14,462 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2017-05-16 10:36:14,470 INFO o.a.j.e.u.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must contain the string: '.functions.'
2017-05-16 10:36:14,470 INFO o.a.j.e.u.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must not contain the string: '.gui.'
2017-05-16 10:36:15,326 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Running test (1494911175326)
2017-05-16 10:36:15,410 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group
2017-05-16 10:36:15,410 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group.
2017-05-16 10:36:15,410 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2017-05-16 10:36:15,411 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=1 perThread=1000.0 delayedStart=false
2017-05-16 10:36:15,426 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2017-05-16 10:36:15,426 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2017-05-16 10:36:15,441 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: Note: Sample TimeStamps are START times
2017-05-16 10:36:15,442 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.default.encoding is set to ISO-8859-1
2017-05-16 10:36:15,442 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.useNanoTime=true
2017-05-16 10:36:15,442 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.nanoThreadSleep=5000
2017-05-16 10:36:15,493 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
2017-05-16 10:36:15,522 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPHCAbstractImpl: Local host = HYDHTC397604D
2017-05-16 10:36:15,531 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPHC4Impl: HTTP request retry count = 0
2017-05-16 10:36:15,757 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Stored: D:\ApacheJMeter_3.2_Win_O\apache-jmeter-3.2\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin\TC_Login.csv
2017-05-16 10:36:21,130 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-1
2017-05-16 10:36:21,130 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1
2017-05-16 10:36:21,132 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2017-05-16 10:36:21,132 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Close: D:\ApacheJMeter_3.2_Win_O\apache-jmeter-3.2\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin\TC_Login.csv
2017-05-16 10:36:21,134 INFO o.a.j.r.Summariser: summary =      0 in 00:00:00 = ******/s Avg:     0 Min: 9223372036854775807 Max: -9223372036854775808 Err:     0 (0.00%)
2017-05-16 10:36:21,136 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Generating Dashboard
2017-05-16 10:36:21,136 INFO o.a.j.r.d.ReportGenerator: Flushing result collector before report Generation
2017-05-16 10:36:21,137 INFO o.a.j.r.ResultCollector: forced flush through ResultCollector#flushFile
2017-05-16 10:36:21,175 INFO o.a.j.r.p.NormalizerSampleConsumer: Using format, 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm', to parse timeStamp field
2017-05-16 10:36:21,411 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.AggregateConsumer#stopProducing(): beginDate produced 0 samples
2017-05-16 10:36:21,411 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.AggregateConsumer#stopProducing(): endDate produced 0 samples
2017-05-16 10:36:21,413 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.ApdexSummaryConsumer#stopProducing(): apdexSummary produced 0 samples
2017-05-16 10:36:21,413 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.RequestsSummaryConsumer#stopProducing(): requestsSummary produced 0 samples
2017-05-16 10:36:21,422 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.StatisticsSummaryConsumer#stopProducing(): statisticsSummary produced 0 samples
2017-05-16 10:36:21,422 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.Top5ErrorsBySamplerConsumer#stopProducing(): top5ErrorsBySampler produced 0 samples
2017-05-16 10:36:21,423 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.ErrorsSummaryConsumer#stopProducing(): errorsSummary produced 0 samples
2017-05-16 10:36:21,423 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.HitsPerSecondGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): hitsPerSecond produced 0 samples
2017-05-16 10:36:21,435 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.LatencyVSRequestGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): latencyVsRequest produced 0 samples
2017-05-16 10:36:21,435 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.SyntheticResponseTimeDistributionGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): syntheticResponseTimeDistribution produced 0 samples
2017-05-16 10:36:21,436 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.BytesThroughputGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): bytesThroughputOverTime produced 0 samples
2017-05-16 10:36:21,437 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.CodesPerSecondGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): codesPerSecond produced 0 samples
2017-05-16 10:36:21,442 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.ResponseTimeVSRequestGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): responseTimeVsRequest produced 0 samples
2017-05-16 10:36:21,443 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.FilterConsumer#stopProducing(): startIntervalControlerFilter produced 0 samples
2017-05-16 10:36:21,443 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.ActiveThreadsGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): activeThreadsOverTime produced 0 samples
2017-05-16 10:36:21,443 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.TimeVSThreadGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): timeVsThreads produced 0 samples
2017-05-16 10:36:21,444 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.ResponseTimeDistributionGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): responseTimeDistribution produced 0 samples
2017-05-16 10:36:21,444 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.TransactionsPerSecondGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): transactionsPerSecond produced 0 samples
2017-05-16 10:36:21,445 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.ResponseTimePercentilesGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): responseTimePercentiles produced 0 samples
2017-05-16 10:36:21,451 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.ResponseTimePercentilesOverTimeGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): responseTimePercentilesOverTime produced 0 samples
2017-05-16 10:36:21,452 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.ResponseTimeOverTimeGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): responseTimesOverTime produced 0 samples
2017-05-16 10:36:21,452 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.ConnectTimeOverTimeGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): connectTimeOverTime produced 0 samples
2017-05-16 10:36:21,453 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.LatencyOverTimeGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): latenciesOverTime produced 0 samples
2017-05-16 10:36:21,454 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.FilterConsumer#stopProducing(): nameFilter produced 112 samples
2017-05-16 10:36:21,454 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.FilterConsumer#stopProducing(): dateRangeFilter produced 24 samples
2017-05-16 10:36:21,454 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.NormalizerSampleConsumer#stopProducing(): normalizer produced 8 samples
2017-05-16 10:36:21,455 INFO o.a.j.r.p.CsvFileSampleSource: produce(): 8 samples produced in 224ms on channel 0
2017-05-16 10:36:21,455 INFO o.a.j.r.d.ReportGenerator: Exporting data using exporter:'html' of className:'org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.HtmlTemplateExporter'
2017-05-16 10:36:21,460 INFO o.a.j.r.d.HtmlTemplateExporter: Will generate dashboard in folder: D:\ApacheJMeter_3.2_Win_O\apache-jmeter-3.2\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin\Output
2017-05-16 10:36:21,467 WARN o.a.j.r.d.HtmlTemplateExporter: No serie matches the series_filter: series_filter in graph: hitsPerSecond
2017-05-16 10:36:21,469 WARN o.a.j.r.d.HtmlTemplateExporter: No serie matches the series_filter: series_filter in graph: latencyVsRequest
2017-05-16 10:36:21,501 WARN o.a.j.r.d.HtmlTemplateExporter: No serie matches the series_filter: series_filter in graph: syntheticResponseTimeDistribution
2017-05-16 10:36:21,505 WARN o.a.j.r.d.HtmlTemplateExporter: No serie matches the series_filter: series_filter in graph: bytesThroughputOverTime
2017-05-16 10:36:21,506 WARN o.a.j.r.d.HtmlTemplateExporter: No serie matches the series_filter: series_filter in graph: codesPerSecond
2017-05-16 10:36:21,508 WARN o.a.j.r.d.HtmlTemplateExporter: No serie matches the series_filter: series_filter in graph: responseTimeVsRequest
2017-05-16 10:36:21,651 INFO o.a.j.r.d.HtmlTemplateExporter: Report will be generated in: D:\ApacheJMeter_3.2_Win_O\apache-jmeter-3.2\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin\Output, creating folder structure
2017-05-16 10:36:23,688 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Dashboard generated
```

also updated my user.properties file with vaues from reportgenerator.properties and saveservice properties. 
Can you help me to understand why details under section of APDEX,Statistics , errors etc are blank while generating the report.
Content of my csv file is as follow:

```
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,grpThreads,allThreads,Latency,IdleTime,Connect
16/05/2017 10:36,153,Home,200,"Number of samples in transaction : 1, number of failing samples : 0",Thread Group 1-1,,true,,1896,537,1,1,0,105,0
16/05/2017 10:36,210,Login,200,"Number of samples in transaction : 3, number of failing samples : 0",Thread Group 1-1,,true,,5733,3085,1,1,0,14,0
16/05/2017 10:36,9,NewItem,200,"Number of samples in transaction : 1, number of failing samples : 0",Thread Group 1-1,,true,,1896,727,1,1,0,1,0
16/05/2017 10:36,10,SelectType,200,"Number of samples in transaction : 1, number of failing samples : 0",Thread Group 1-1,,true,,1896,755,1,1,0,2,0
16/05/2017 10:36,23,ClickNext,200,"Number of samples in transaction : 2, number of failing samples : 0",Thread Group 1-1,,true,,3792,1611,1,1,0,5,0
16/05/2017 10:36,53,ClickFinish,200,"Number of samples in transaction : 5, number of failing samples : 0",Thread Group 1-1,,true,,7893,4496,1,1,0,13,0
16/05/2017 10:36,11,Cancel,200,"Number of samples in transaction : 1, number of failing samples : 0",Thread Group 1-1,,true,,1896,685,1,1,0,3,0
16/05/2017 10:36,17,Logout,200,"Number of samples in transaction : 1, number of failing samples : 0",Thread Group 1-1,,true,,1896,679,1,1,0,5002,0
```

Comment: Hi,Any feedback on answer ? if ok you should accept it and upvote.Thx

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your answer. I am new to JMeter, kindly guide if I am wrong. I have added jmeter.save.saveservice properties in user.properties file and i need to run script and generate dashboard report through online . Is there a way to check Generate Parent sample value through command line and set it accordingly.

Comment: please read the answer, just uncheck the grnerate parent sample.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't follow pre-requisites as described here:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#configuration_requirements

Mainly , you checked "Generate parent sample" which must be unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience some weird characters in the CSV can break the test result generation.

For instance it can be something like having `&quot;` in the XML inserted by the JMeter editor.